# Content-Type in header being changed when fpassthru called

Tags: php, header, amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to force the browser to bring up a download dialog when a user clicks on a link to an image being served by Amazon AWS. I have the following PHP script to do this which is mostly working. However, it is failing on an iPad producing a webpage of garbled text instead. Despite setting the Content-Type in the header to "image/jpeg" the resultant file is showing up as a CSV which is presumably causing the issue on the iPad (whereas the desktop browsers are correcting to the right type).

If I put a `die()` in place before the `fpassthru($fp)` the Content-Type is showing up as a JPEG.

How can I ensure my Content-Type is correctly set and delivered as a JPEG?

```
$urlComponents = parse_url($url); // where URL is the URL to the image on AWS
if (!isset($urlComponents['path'])) {
    die();
}
$pathParts = pathinfo($urlComponents['path']);
if (!isset($pathParts['basename'])) {
    die();
} else {
    $image = $pathParts['basename'];
}

$fp = fopen($url, 'rb');

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$image");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

fpassthru($fp);

fclose($fp);
```

The code is based on the example given on PHP.net's website http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php.

Comment: Do you have any extra code? Something that could break the headers?

Comment: From php.net : "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. "

Comment: This is part of a CakePHP app. My code example is the View. There shouldn't be any other headers being set before this code (I've successfully done this in the past). As stated in my question if I die() before fpassthru the header appears to have been set correctly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fpassthru doesn't set headers so the problem is before that or after (post-controller code)

Comment: Thanks. The problem occurs after the script. So I've been able to fix it by placing a die() at the end of the script as I don't need anything that runs after that code.

Answer (score 0):

I should mention that having a space between the header name and the semicolon before its value is as good as not having a header. and will default to text/html e.g

```
header('Content-type : image/jpeg'); //will not work. will default to text/html
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); //will work
```

Also it is Content-type not Content-Type! Field names are case sensitive

> 4.2 Message Headers
>
> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names
>   are case-insensitive.**

[Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

Obviously you want to make sure there is no other output before the header is set. Output buffering is a good way to ensure your not printing anything to the browser.